# Rigged character not controlling all parts

Tags: animation, rigging, parent

So I have rigged my character and parented the skeleton to the mesh. Home bones move great but others arent moving at all. The hand, for instance, moves with the wrist bone but two knuckle pieces dont follow. As well, the head is one joined mesh yet the bones seem to pick and choose what part of the head they interact with. I am very new to rigging so I am lost as to what the problem is. Any help is appreciated. Attached are the pics of what is happening.[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Autoweights don't work well on multiple separate meshes.  You can paint some parts manually-- perfectly reasonable for a robot like this, it's probably just a matter of selecting the right VG and assigning-- or you can separate the laggards to a different object and then data transfer weights from the original mesh.

Comment: Ty for the reply. Would you be able to elaborate or point me to a good resource? also what does VG mean? I'm pretty new to rigging so I dont know much. I went into weight paint mode but cant seem to figure out how to select a bone to paint on.

Comment: VG = "vertex group".  You should be googling "blender weight paint" and "blender assign to vertex group".  Try to follow along with some tutorials, likely videos.